# How to get keypress event in console

Tags: c, events

I want to get `on_key_press_event` without pressing Enter.
And of course I need the character code. Is there solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend having a read through [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer/C_Console_IO). I think

```
getchar()
```

might be what you're after.

EDIT: In fact possibly

```
#include <conio.h>
_getch()
```

would work better for you as it does not require the end of line character (enter button to be pressed). For windows refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and for unix systems this seems to be included in the [curses library](https://www.google.ca/search?&q=curses%20library).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

There's no cross-platform way to do unbuffered input from stdin. You can use [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) if you're on a Unix-based distribution. On Windows you can use [getch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).