# Getch just refuses to work for me as it should

Tags: c

I am new to C and so I wanted to get more experience with the libraries function. When I started fiddling with getch() I could't for the life of me get it to work. All that happened was that the characters were echoed back to the console and I could type multiple and even press enter without it continuing throughout the program. Here is a little test code I made. Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>



int main(){
   char i = '9';
   i = getch();
   printf("%c", i);

}
```

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers although I could've been more clear on what I wanted. I want to be getch() to be used almost like fgets() except I don't want it to echo and I want the console to accept the character entered immediately without any enter key pressed. Is getch the wrong tool to do this with?

Comment: It is not really clear what was your goal...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get keypress event in console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973046/how-to-get-keypress-event-in-console)

Comment: You may want to look into the `ncurses` library.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
i = getch();
```

to

```
i = getchar();
```

`getchar()` is a standard function that gets a character from the stdin.

`getch()` is non-standard. It gets a character from the keyboard (which could be different from stdin) and does not echo it.

Comment: Non-standard *and* non-portable (meaning it's not guaranteed to exist, let alone reproduce the desired behaviour), as with everything from `<conio.h>`. Also change `char i` to `int i` as `getchar` returns `int`, and `printf("%c", i);` to `if (i != EOF) { putchar(i); }` to handle `EOF` and read errors correctly.

Answer (score 1):

getch() is a function is used to end or close main function used in windows with conio header file.
there is no use of stdlib header function it is used while taking string
as a function.
%c is used to print characters.
if u wants to print i than go like as mention below:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
int i = 9;
printf("%d", i);
getch();
}
```